# Errno socket error occurs when I retrieve file from url with python urllib

Tags: python, sockets, url, download, urllib

I try to download a .tiff file from NASA. When doing it in the browser it works out fine. When trying it with the following python code

```
import urllib
f = urllib.FancyURLopener()
url = "https://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/servlet/RenderData?si=1696692&cs=gs&format=TIFF&width=3600&height=1800"
f.retrieve(url, "test.TIFF")
```

I get the error

> IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)

I found one similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error) solving the error by creating a new SSLContext. However I can not figure out how to save a downloaded file as required in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with python 2 using urllib2 that works for me:

```
import urllib2
url = "https://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/servlet/RenderData?si=1696692&cs=gs&format=TIFF&width=3600&height=1800"
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = f.read()
with open("img.TIFF", "wb") as imgfile:
    imgfile.write(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
url = 'https://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/servlet/RenderData?si=1696692&cs=gs&format=TIFF&width=3600&height=1800'
urlretrieve(url, 'result.TIFF')
```

Not sure if this will work in Python 2. Will update my answer later.

Comment: in python 2 I can do 

`urllib.urlretrieve(url, "result.TIFF")`

however I still get the same error